# Must size() == end() - begin()? What about the cast?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

From what I understand, the purpose of `size_type` and `difference_type` is **not** merely the sign -- it was also meant to address e.g. segmented architectures and such, where they might be of different sizes.

With that context, if I have a container with random-access iterators, is it safe for me to perform a `static_cast` between its `difference_type` and `size_type` values at will, on the grounds that `end() - begin()` *must* always be equal to `size()`, when either is casted?

(The use case, for example, is to create a container whose size is equal to the number of elements between two iterators, or the reverse: to copy a container of a certain size onto a range delimited by iterators.)

Anything I should watch out for before casting (e.g. loss of data)?

Comment: Apart from the formatting (it's a table), this is in § 23.2.1: `expression: a.size(), return: size_type, operational semantics: distance(a.begin(),
a.end()), complexity:
constant` Is that what you're looking for? `distance` would be in there somewhere too, presumably making it more specific.

Comment: @chris: Oh I haven't seen that table... so it seems like going forward is safe. How about the reverse -- how do you go from `difference_type` to `size_type` safely?

Comment: I have not seen segmented architectures for quite some time already... and if you do, to make your container work you will need to do quite some magic, so can tackle the potential change of types. Note that in some implementations that is exactly how it is handled (i.e. a vector contains three pointers, and `size()` is the difference between the begin and end pointers.

Comment: @Mehrdad, From the same table, looks like `size_type` covers the positive half of `difference_type`.

Comment: @chris: If you could post that as an answer (with some link to the table if possible) that would be awesome! :)

Comment: @Mehrdad, It'll take me some time, but I can work at it.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I have a fair chunk. I guess I'll post what I have now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what the [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) has to say on various things here:

§ 23.2.1

```
Expression: difference_type
Return Type: signed integer type
Operational Semantics: -
Assertion/note, pre-/post-condition: is identical to the difference type of iterator and const_iterator
Complexity: compile-time

Expression: size_type
Return Type: unsigned integer type
Operational Semantics: -
Assertion/note, pre-/post-condition: size_type can represent any non-negative value of difference_type
Complexity: compile-time

Expression: size()
Return Type: size_type
Operational Semantics: distance(begin(),end()) 
Assertion/note, pre-/post-condition: -
Complexity: constant
```

Let's make sure `size()` is equivalent to `end() - begin()`:

§ 24.4.4/4

```
distance():
Eﬀects: If InputIterator meets the requirements of random access iterator, 
returns (last - first); otherwise, returns the number of increments needed 
to get from first to last
```

Since your container has random-access iterators, this holds true. That's that. As you can see in the first box,

```
size_type can represent any non-negative value of difference_type
```

From that, we have that the cast from `difference_type` to `size_type` should be valid for all non-negative values.

Comment: So to clarify, a cast from `size_type` to `difference_type` must also be valid, right? (Since it's valid for the maximum value, `size()`)

Comment: @Mehrdad, From the bottom block, `size_type` looks to be a subset of `difference_type`. Therefore, a cast from the former to the latter should be valid, as anything in a subset is also in the superset. The other way around requires that the element be checked to make sure it's in the subset.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is always safe. This historical issue existed since first specification of C language, where `ptrdiff_t` is not guaranteed to cover the entire positive range of `size_t`. For obvious reasons, this issue carries over to the specification of `std::vector`.

With standard C++ containers, it is guaranteed that `size_type` covers the non-negative range of `difference_type`, but the reverse coverage is not guaranteed.

However, the relationship between `size()` and `end() - begin()` for a standard container can be guaranteed by other means. The implementation is free to impose its own limitations on the maximum container size, which are exposed through `container::max_size()` function. It can artificially restrict the maximum size to make sure the subtraction never overflows.

P.S. I'd say that the reason for `difference_type`'s existence is just the sign and nothing else. To be completely "safe" `difference_type` should be 1 bit longer than `size_type`. This is often difficult to achieve in practice, which is why it is not required by the language specification.

Comment: To be fair, the only time you need the full range of `size_t` is when `sizeof(T)==1` and the container fills over half of memory. This is rare going on impossible.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: That would be true for platforms with flat memory model. I still defiantly keep a special place in my heart for segmented-memory platforms :)

Comment: @JesseGood, Oh, that was my misreading "still" for "will", then, lol. It makes much more sense like that.