# What is the outcome of std::distance(v.begin(), v.end()) when v is bigger than INT_MAX?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, integer-overflow

Consider this code:

```
std::vector<char>::size_type size = static_cast<std::vector<char>::size_type>(std::numeric_limits<std::vector<char>::difference_type>::max()) + 1;
std::vector<char> v(size);
std::vector<char>::difference_type diff = std::distance(v.begin(), v.end());
```

where *size_type* is the same as *size_t* (unsigned int), and *difference_type* is the same as *ptrdiff_t* (signed int).

If the size of the vector is bigger than the limit of *difference_type*, will the *std::distance* function return a negative value?

Comment: have you tried by yourself?

Comment: Are you sure that size_type is signed? I don't think the standard allows that.

Comment: size_type is unsigned, usually size_t

Comment: @Jepessen I tried to test, but the memory required is very large and I get bad alloc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must size() == end() - begin()? What about the cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660774/must-size-end-begin-what-about-the-cast)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a random access iterator type, `distance(a,b)` is defined to be `b-a`. Subtraction of random access iterators has a precondition:

> pre: there exists a value `n` of type `difference_type` such that `a + n == b`.

So, if the vector size is too large for `difference_type`, then you break that precondition, giving undefined behaviour (perhaps a negative result; perhaps something else).

Comment: I'm writing a custom container, should I implement this behaviour?

Comment: @WesleyCerasoPrudencio: You should implement all the relevant container and iterator requirements. It's up to you what to do where the behaviour is undefined.